# how to validate the number of character entered in tinymce(gem) editor rails application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using tinymce text editor in my rails application. I need to validate maximum length for text field using javascript. Using `tinymce.activeEditor.getContent()` this i can able to get the content of the text box. But it getting values with html elements like `<p><strong>welcome <em>to</em> <span style="color: #99cc00;">Ruby on Rails</span> .</strong></p>` so i can't able to count the number of letters entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at here http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/TinyMCE3x:How_to_limit_number_of_characters/words it will help you to validate number of character in a field very easily.